# Play Slick "LIKE" query

Tags: mysql, playframework, slick

Trying to execute `LIKE` query in `Play Framework` using `Slick`, but it simply grabs all records from database (`MySQL`) and sometimes I get errors.

```
def find(term: String): Future[Seq[Equipment]] =
db.run(equipment.filter(_.name like "%"+term+"%" ).result)
```

Probably, the Option field be added to function return type. And the error text:

```
[error] application - 

! @72nbkeip7 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/find?test] ->

play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[SQLTimeoutException: Timeout after 1000ms of waiting for a connection.]]
at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:280)
at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:206)
at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)
at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:188)
at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:98)
at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:100)
at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:99)
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:346)
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:345)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: Timeout after 1000ms of waiting for a connection.
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.getConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:227)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.getConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:182)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:93)
at slick.jdbc.hikaricp.HikariCPJdbcDataSource.createConnection(HikariCPJdbcDataSource.scala:12)
at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.conn$lzycompute(JdbcBackend.scala:415)
at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.conn(JdbcBackend.scala:414)
at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$SessionDef$class.prepareStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:297)
at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.prepareStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:407)
at slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.results(StatementInvoker.scala:33)
at slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.iteratorTo(StatementInvoker.scala:22)
```

Suggestions, please.

Comment: Turn query logging in slick to see the query executed. `<logger name="slick.jdbc" level="DEBUG"/>`. The error you show is not related to this query, do you have these errors in production?

Comment: "nmat, It helped , now i know that problem was in my url , I wrote `http://localhost:9000/find?test` instead of `http://localhost:9000/find?term=test`. But could I make the first url type work? Current routes looks like this: `GET    /find         controllers.EquipmentController.find(term: String ?= "")`

Comment: I'm not sure. Try  to search on how to use query parameters in play without value. That's unrelated to the original question though